# Inventory Macro - copying information from one row of sheet to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a Macro for inventory where essentially, Sheet 1 has all the information including barcode #, product name, and product size in rows. In Sheet 2 I have a button that, when clicked, allows me to scan a barcode of a product in my hand.

What I want is that when the barcode that I scan matches one of the barcodes in Sheet 1, all the other information pertaining to that product gets copied over into Sheet 2, or another sheet. I'm not sure which would be easier.
Right now the code that I have only adds some additional information next to the barcode that was matched. I'm not sure how to add that information as well as the original information from sheet 1 to a new sheet.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim MatchRow As Variant
Dim code As Variant
Dim matchedCell As Range

barcode = InputBox("Please scan a barcode and hit enter if you need to")

' verify that there is a successful match in the searched range

Set Shta = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set Shtb = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set Sheet1Range = Sheet1.Range("D2:D108")

If Not IsError(Application.Match(barcode, Sheet1Range, 0)) Then
    MatchRow = Application.Match(barcode, Sheet1Range, 0) '<-- get the row number
    MatchCatalog = MatchRow + 1
    Set matchedCell = Range("D" & MatchCatalog) '<-- set the range (add 1 row since you are starting from row 2)
    matchedCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = Now
    matchedCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = MatchCatalog
    matchedCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = barcode


    'option 2: without setting the range
    Range("AE" & MatchRow).Offset(1, 2).Value = Now
End If

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!
Even some help on how to copy data from an entire row into a sheet would be helpful as a start.

Comment: If you are just looking to bring over 1 row, you can do this with a VLOOKUP. Just import your scan to a cell and use that as the first criteria

Comment: You can also use the `Range.Find` method and copy the entire row of the found cell.

Comment: @urdearboy how do i go about importing this scan into a cell? I've only know to create the popup box that I scan into

Comment: Use your macro to drop the barcode into a cell. Then you can just use VLOOKUP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import your information with a `VLOOKUP` or `INDEX(MATCH())` depending on how your data is set up. You can just use the macro to only drop your `barcode` into a cell. This will be the look up value (first criteria) in your `VLOOKUP`

The below will put your barcode on `A1`

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim Barcode
barcode = InputBox("Please scan a barcode and hit enter if you need to")

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1") = Barcode

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I have little to no vba experience lol I'll do some research on vlookups but you've definitely helped! I appreciate it